# How to return the highest value from multiple columns to a new column in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies for the opaque question name (not sure how to word it). I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['tom', 1,1,6,4],
        ['tom', 1,2,2,3],
        ['tom', 1,2,3,1],
        ['tom', 2,3,2,7],
        ['jim', 1,4,3,6],
        ['jim', 2,6,5,3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Day','A','B','C']) 
df = df.groupby(by=['Name','Day']).agg('sum').reset_index()
df
```

[image]

I would like to add another column that returns text according to which column of `A,B,C` is the highest:

For example I would like `Apple` if `A` is highest, `Banana` if `B` is highest, and `Carrot` if `C` is highest. So in the example above the values for the 4 columns should be:

```
New Col
Carrot
Apple
Banana
Carrot
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: what if there is no unique max value?

Comment: generally there is not a unique answer (the values are floats to 3 decimals) but in the case of a tie either of the two values is fine in this instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) along `axis=1` with [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
dct = {'A': 'Apple', 'B': 'Banana', 'C': 'Carrot'}
df['New col'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].idxmax(axis=1).map(dct)
```

Result:

```
  Name  Day  A   B  C New col
0  jim    1  4   3  6  Carrot
1  jim    2  6   5  3   Apple
2  tom    1  5  11  8  Banana
3  tom    2  3   2  7  Carrot
```

Comment: This is great - thanks very much! (i will accept answer when i can)

Answer (score 2):

@ShubhamSharma's answer is better than this, but here is another option:

```
df['New col'] = np.where((df['A'] > df['B']) & (df['A'] > df['C']), 'Apple', 'Carrot')
df['New col'] = np.where((df['B'] > df['A']) & (df['B'] > df['C']), 'Banana', df['New col'])
```

output:

```
    Name    Day A   B   C   New col
0   jim 1   4   3   6   Carrot
1   jim 2   6   5   3   Apple
2   tom 1   5   11  8   Banana
3   tom 2   3   2   7   Carrot
```